# Wrong Header Position after list of Symbols, scrreprt twoside

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, double-sided

i use the documentclass scrreprt for my thesis with twoside (book printing).

I have the Problem that when i am switching from \pagenumbering{Roman} to
\pagenumbering{arabic}, two pages are righthanded one after another (see my added figures). Otherwise, the pages are always alternating left and right. It's just the transition from the indexes to the main text.

The header "Einleitung" should be on the left side. Is there a way to force set it to the left or anything.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%Dokumentdefinition%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%[coloredheadlines]{thesis}

%\documentclass[twoside,11pt,a4paper,bibliography=totocnumbered,numbers=noenddot]%{scrreprt} 


\documentclass
[   twoside,       % Einseitiger oder zweiseitiger Druck?
    fontsize=12pt,      % Bezug: 12-Punkt Schriftgröße
    %DIV=15,            % Randaufteilung, siehe Dokumentation "KOMA"-Script
    %BCOR=17mm,         % Bindekorrektur: Innen 17mm Platz lassen. Copyshop-getestet
    headsepline,      % Unter Kopfzeile Trennlinie (aus: headnosepline)
    %footsepline,       % Über Fußzeile Trennlinie (aus: footnosepline)
    %open=right,          % Neue Kapitel im zweiseitigen Druck rechts beginnen lassen
    paper=a4,            % Seitenformat A4
    abstract=false,     % Abstract einbinden
    listof=totoc,        % Div. Verzeichnisse ins Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
    bibliography=totoc,  % Literaturverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
    titlepage,           % Titelseite aktivieren
    headinclude=true,    % Seiten-Head in die Satzspiegelberechnung mit einbeziehen
    footinclude=false,   % Seiten-Foot nicht in die Satzspiegelberechnung mit einbeziehen
    numbers=noenddot     % Gliederungsnummern ohne abschließenden Punkt darstellen
]   {scrreprt}


%\documentclass[twoside,11pt,a4paper,bibliography=totocnumbered,numbers=noenddot]%{scrartcl} 
%scrreprt

%\documentclass[twoside,11pt,a4paper,bibliography=totocnumbered,numbers=noenddot, coloredheadlines]{thesis} 


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=30mm, right=25mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=5mm, footskip=12mm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Inputfile für Packages (hält das Dokument sauber)%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            
\input{Main_Packages}

%\sloppy                    %"schlampiger" Blocksatz
\parindent0cm                   %Absatzeinzug

\usepackage{setspace}               %Zeilenabstand
\onehalfspacing
%\singlespacing
%\doublespacing

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%hier startet das eigentliche Dokument%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage   %%% Für Twoside damit es keine leeren Seiten gibt, ansonsten oneside verwenden

\begin{document}
                
\pagenumbering{Roman}               %Seitennummerierung auf römisch geändert


\begin{titlepage}                   %gesondert formatierte Titelseite
%\input{00_Deckblatt.tex}           %extrenes .tex Dokument als Titelblatt Beispiel Uni-Magdeburg
\end{titlepage}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

%\includepdf[pages=-]{}                     %Aufgabenstellung als PDF einbinden
%\chapter*{Aufgabenstellung}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Aufgabenstellung}
\pagebreak

\setcounter{page}{1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{01_Notwendiges.tex}%Vorwort, Editorial, Erklärungen, Vermerke%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 

\newpage
%\begin{singlespace}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Verzeichnisse%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}    %countertiefe für Verzeichnisse
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}       %Auflistungstiefe für Verzeichnisse
\chaptermark{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents                        %Befehl für Inhaltsverzeichnis
\newpage

\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}         % Kein Zeilenumbruch / Abstand bz w nach Kapitel sortieren
\listoffigures                          %Befehl für Abbildungsverzeichnis
\markboth{Abbildungsverzeichnis}{}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}      
%\chaptermark{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\newpage
\listoftables                           %Befehl für Tabellenverzeichnis
\markboth{Tabellenverzeichnis}{}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
%\chaptermark{Tabellenverzeichnis}

\endgroup
\newpage



\chapter*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}    
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}       %ins Inhaltsverzeichnis schreiben
\chaptermark{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\begin{acronym}[SEPSEP]




\end{acronym}



%\newpage
%\pagenumbering{Roman}              %Seitennummerierung auf römisch
\chapter*{Symbolverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Symbolverzeichnis}   
\chaptermark{Symbolverzeichnis}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{KÜRZEL}[ABKÜRZUNG]{BESCHREIBUNG}
\acro{R}[ABKÜRZUNG]{BESCHREIBUNG}
\end{acronym}

%\pagenumbering{Roman}              %Seitennummerierung auf römisch

%\end{singlespace}
%\cleardoublepage               % hat bei twoside die Kopfzeile durcheinander gebracht
 



%Vorlagenkapitel
%\onehalfspacing 



\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}          %ab hier arabische Seitenzahlen
%\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{Einleitung}




\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use \clearpage or \pagebreak but \cleardoublepage to separate the two parts. Or better use \frontmatter and \mainmatter that will also setup the numbering.

Comment: \frontmatter and \mainmatter doesn't work with scrreprt. I tried scrbook but it also doesn't work. It creates a blank space und same double right header.

Comment: well you naturally will have to clean up also your code. E.g. `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` clearly disables the ability to detect twoside. And all your pagebreak and manual numbering setting aren't good either. But as you use local packages, your document cannot be tested and corrected.

Comment: if i use scrbook i get a lot of empty pages and i don't know why. Cleaned the code and used \frontmatter and \mainmatter. Also the \frontmatter numbers are not big as with scrreprt

Comment: you get empty pages exactly because of the reason you asked a question here: because the code tries to ensure that right pages are on the right. If you want to allow chapters to start also on a left page, use `open=any`.